# I have $17$ red and $8$ blue balls how can i distribute them to max $5$ groups and every group will have more red balls then blue ones

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways you can distribute $17$ red and $8$ blue balls to $5$ groups.Each group will have more red balls than blue ones

Comment: you mean in "how many different ways can you?"

Comment: @alperakyuz Welcome to Math SE! Please show some effort and mention where you are stuck, and change your title to something *other than* the question to make your question better.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "distribute ...". Do you mean: "Partition these balls into $\leq5$ nonempty heaps", or "Allocate these balls to $5$ labeled boxes whereby some may be left empty", or do you have some other concept in mind?

Comment: Blue:  $ 1,  1,   2,   2,   2=8$                                                                               Red : $  4, 4,    3,   3,   3=17$                                                                            So we have five groups;$(1, 4), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2,3)$ these are five groups each containing 5 balls  in which red ball are more than blue one.Is the number of ball in each group limited to 5?

Comment: every group has to have at least $1$ ball but there are no limits to max number of balls in a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this question as follows: In how many ways can $17$ red balls and $8$ blue balls be partitioned into $\leq5$ nonempty heaps such that on each heap there are more red balls than blue balls.

This is an intricate problem, and it will not be solved here. First a simplification: We may incorporate a red ball into each of the blue balls, and then have to partition the $9$ leftover red balls and the $8$ blue balls into $\leq5$ heaps, each of them containing at least one red ball.

Therefore we begin by partitioning the $9$ red balls into $\leq5$ nonempty heaps. If I got them all there are $23$ such partitions, namely
$$(9), (8,1),(7,2),(7,1,1),(6,3),(6,2,1),(6,1,1,1), (5,4),(5,3,1),(5,2,2),$$
$$(5,2,1,1),(5,1,1,1,1),(4,4,1),(4,3,2),(4,3,1,1),(4,2,2,1),(4,2,1,1,1),$$
$$(3,3,3),(3,3,2,1),(3,3,1,1,1),(3,2,2,2),(3,2,2,1,1),(2,2,2,2,1)\ .$$
Now we have to treat each of these partitions in turn, by distributing the $8$ blue balls arbitrarily on the present heaps. Since the heaps are unlabeled and the occurring sizes come in multiplicities this is not just a stars and bars problem. There are about a dozen different types with respect to these multiplicities; therefore a lot of combinatorial handywork is needed in order to arrive at the final result.